# iPhone How to prevent my app from entering background when lock screen?

Tags: iphone, background

When press the lock button in app,system will call :

```
-(void) applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application and
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

So how can I do to make my app only resignActive but not enter background,and I can run my timer when screen locked(Timer can't execute in background mode).

One method is set the property "Application does not run in background" in .plist to YES,it worked, but my app can never enter background again,however I want it will enter background when press the home button.

**Update:** I want to play some music in my app at a certain time,just like a music alarm,and I still want it works fine when the screen locked,because keep the screen on may waste a lot of battery,and I don't need to do any thing when user press the home button and exit my app.

Comment: You can check out one tutorial that tells how to prevent an app from entering in background-  http://blog.marcopeluso.com/2009/08/23/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping/

Comment: Thank you,however I think the way can only make the system not entering deep sleep,but not prevent my app from entering in background.

Comment: Since when does an app enter the background when you lock the device?? I only ever have it fire when the user hits the home button or switches apps.

Answer (score 1):

Open your Info.plist file and add Application does not run in background.  Set value to YES.

Answer (score 0):

Application must have special privileges to do any processing in background such as Audio service/Voip service/Location service.

"I can run my timer when screen locked(Timer can't execute in background mode)"
you cannot run a timer in background which will keep running without using any tentrum and doing so...apple will not accept your application on appstore - that's the worst side if you are targeting appstore...

Comment: Actually I don't want do any thing in background,I want to know is that can my app keep in foreground when turned off the screen in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can not prevent your app from entering the background. This is decided by the operating system (iOS) and is out of control from applications. However, from reading your updated question, I don't think this is what you need to do.

You can execute background tasks with `[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler;]` (see [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a)). If you want to have something happening after a certain interval, check out `[UIApplication scheduleLocalNotification:]`.

Some services such as VOIP, Audio and CoreLocation are allowed to run in background. Using these for other than their intended purposes (for example, playing silent audio) may risk your app being rejected.

Note that there is nothing you can do to prevent your application from entering the background. It is just that some tasks are allowed to execute in the background. Because of this, you cannot do GUI operations and NSTimers will probably not fire (at least I know some cases where they don't).

It would help knowing what you want to run in the background in order to suggest a solution.

Comment: I really don't want my app enter background,but as you said,can I think that press the lock button in my app is just like press the home button,my app should enter background.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are playing audio BEFORE the move to background you cannot start audio playback when the app is moved to the background or the screen is locked (which has some weird specifics) suffice to say, its as if you were in the background without actually receiving the applicationDidEnterBackground notification.

The best you can do is schedule a local notification, but in this case your music is limited to 30 seconds and must be part of your application bundle.